# Why was Troy also called Holy Ilios?

Tags: ancient-history

Is there some evidence in the [Iliad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad) and the [Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey) why Troy was capitol and Holy city? Why was it the Holy city?

Comment: This seems more like a question for Mythology.SE.

Comment: Maybe seems,but remember to Mohenjodaro,-the Holy river made Holy City.

Answer (score 5):

In the Iliad it's a holy city because it was founded by the Gods. More important than that however, was its walls were built by the gods, and those walls were guarded by holy guards.  Troy's walls in the Iliad were built by the gods Poseidon and Apollo.  They are said to be Divine as a way of demonstrating in the story that the walls are absolutely undoubtedly impenetrable by mortal man.   Built by the Gods,  one of only two city walls said to be unbreakable with Troy's walls being the better of the two impressive specimen of walls because their walls were not only unbreakable but blessed by the gods too.  The finest walls in antiquity stamped so by the Gods themselves.   The Gods look at those walls and felt pride.

> [Plot and Point of View in the Iliad](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ms0LT9W1VYIC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=why+is+troy+called+a+holy+city&source=bl&ots=P0-nHJfw6p&sig=ugCcHEWZ1Kg0Sq_fnN-kxcN3EvE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit0qiR8IDaAhWMwFkKHZ4CAS4Q6AEIdDAH#v=onepage&q=Holy&f=false)
>   Of coarse, Troy is a holy city with sacred walls, one of only two cities in the Iliad whose walls are so designated. ( The other is Boiotian Thebes[4.378].  The Achaean wall is not holy or Devine.  It was built, so Poseidon complains, without proper sacrifices to the Gods( 7-450).
>
> The guards of Troy are also called "holy", at 24.681.
>
> [In the Iliad, the only "unbreakable", artifact possessed by mortals are the walls of Troy(21.447) page 109](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ms0LT9W1VYIC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=why+is+troy+called+a+holy+city&source=bl&ots=P0-nHJfw6p&sig=ugCcHEWZ1Kg0Sq_fnN-kxcN3EvE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit0qiR8IDaAhWMwFkKHZ4CAS4Q6AEIdDAH#v=onepage&q=Holy&f=false)

In the Iliad they have Poseidon comparing the walls of the Greek invaders camp with the walls of Holy Troy.  With the God noting that the very Fine Greek walls were not built with a sacrifice to the gods.  Poseidon observes these Greeks think they can build walls better than the Gods.

In Greek stories, pride can be a fatal flaw.  The Greek gods were jealous 
gods who cursed (actively abused) mortals who offended them with their arrogance.

> Immediately after the Achaians complete their work, Poseidon complains to his brother, Zeus, that the new wall threatens to rival in glory the circuit(walls) that the gods themselves constructed when they made Troy a city (7.446-53):
>   ..

The Gods taking pride in their work.

> The fame of this wall will reach as far as the dawn spreads her light:  and they will forget the wall that I and Phoibos (Apollo) labored to build for the hero Laomedon.

**Source:**

- [Plot and Point of View in the Iliad](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ms0LT9W1VYIC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=why+is+troy+called+a+holy+city&source=bl&ots=P0-nHJfw6p&sig=ugCcHEWZ1Kg0Sq_fnN-kxcN3EvE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit0qiR8IDaAhWMwFkKHZ4CAS4Q6AEIdDAH#v=onepage&q=Holy&f=false)

Comment: This answer is excellent ,also very well explained,-"pride can be a fatal flow".From another focus I think- in that specifical area of site of Troy-there are many nature "energetic" fields,(meteorological phenomenons)like-springs of water, also hot spring,rivers,sea,mountains,vulcan(Lemnos-Hephestus),caves,meteors(Atena),fog(Poseidon),sea snakes and dragon (Poseidon-Typhoon).All of these phenomenons are posted in one place,and it  was  ideally for story of gods and their's battle in Iliad. Conclusion - site of Troy is a specifically area,reach with a "geo-gifts ".

Comment: .....and I give  to that the precedence over the archaeological finds,when we find a really site of Homeric Troy.